# ¿Cómo proteger archivos sensibles, evitando que se sincronicen con un repositorio público de Github?

Tags: android-studio, github

Tengo un proyecto realizado en [android-studio](/questions/tagged/android-studio) sincronizado con un repositorio público de Github.

Ahora acabo de añadir a mi proyecto un archivo con datos sensibles que no quiero que se sincronice nunca.

¿Es posible marcarlo desde ahora, para que no se suba a Github en la próxima sincronización ni en ninguna otra?

Estuve mirando entre las opciones y no vi esa posibilidad. Creo haber hecho eso durante el proceso de sincronización, pero no quiero sincronizar de nuevo solamente por ese archivo y por otra parte no quisiera que ocurra una sincronización automática y el archivo vaya a parar al repositorio.

¿Hay alguna forma de marcarlo para no sincronización?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si, con un archivo que se llame [`.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) y ahí agregás los archivos o carpetas que querés que no se sincronice nunca. Por ejemplo:

#### .gitignore

```
*.log
```

Evita que sincronice cualquier archivo con extensión `.log`.

Comment: Pero... ¿dónde va ese archivo, en Android Studio o en Github? ¿Podría poner el nombre completo del archivo?

Comment: En github, en la carpeta principal. Si, podés poner el nombre completo del archivo o path relativo.

Comment: ¿path relativo que quiere decir? El archivo está en la carpeta `app`, ¿tendría que ponerlo así `app/archivo.ext` o así `/app/archivo.ext` o simplemente `archivo.ext`?. Es que en `gitignore` veo algunos así: `/.idea/modules.xml`

Comment: Claro, relativamente de la carpeta, como en la primera opción que pusiste `app/archivo.ext` debería funcionar.

Answer (score 2):

En la documentación puedes encontrar información acerca del archivo [.gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore), si no se encuentra creado lo puedes crear en la raíz de tu proyecto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

básicamente para ignorar archivos que no deseas sean versionados, si no deseas se agregue un directorio completo, agrega:

```
<nombre directorio>/
```

si deseas que no se agreguen archivos con determinada extensión, agrega:

```
*.<extensión de archivo>
```

si deseas que no se agregue determinado archivo, simplemente agrega el nombre:

```
<nombre de archivo>
```

para agregar comentarios simplemente deben iniciar con `#` :

```
# Android Studio captures folder
captures/
```

más información en la **[documentación](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)**.

Answer (score 1):

También tenés que hacer un git rm del archivo para que se borre del repositorio. Si querés podés hacer git rm --cached para conservar la copia local.

Importante esto solo borra el archivo del repositorio sigue estando en la historia. Si tenés información sensible deberías borrarlo de la historia de git

Comment: Aún no se ha subido a Github, no he sincronizado el proyecto.